# CSS: How to make background color around text not flush to the text?

Tags: css, menu, background, hover

I am new to CSS and website design. See the menu on the left on this page:
When you hover over a menu element the background around the text becomes white but I would like the entire row and a little bit over and under the text to become white too, similar to the top menus. Here's the code I have:

```
.child-sidebar-menu
{
    background-color: #DEDEDE;
}

.advanced-sidebar-menu ul li a{

text-decoration: none;
color: black;
border-bottom: 0px;
}

.advanced-sidebar-menu ul li a:hover{
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: 0px;
}

.advanced-sidebar-menu li > ul li a:hover
 {
   color: black;
background-color: white;
 }

.advanced-sidebar-menu ul ul li a{
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 100%;
border-bottom: 0px;
}

.advanced-sidebar-menu ul{
margin: 0 0 0 0px;
list-style: none;
list-style-type: none;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
border-bottom: 0px;
line-height: 200%;
}

.advanced-sidebar-menu ul li{
    list-style:none;
    list-style-type: none;
border-bottom: 0px;


}

.advanced-sidebar-menu li.current_page_item{

    list-style-type: none;
border-bottom: 0px;
}

.advanced-sidebar-menu li.current_page_item a{
    font-weight: bold;
border-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Any easy way to do this? Does it have to do with border and margin?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/D5sdT/

The key points are :

1. Make `<a>` tag `display : block`. This will allow `<a>` to occupy complete horizontal space as `li`
2. Remove `padding` and `margin` from `<li>`. Instead give the same to `<a>`.

Comment: Thanks. I did like you did and it improved alot but there is still some gap on the left between the hover background color and the regular background color. On the right there's no gap.

Comment: This is because of the `ul` tag inside another `ul` tag. By default, `ul` will have some margin on left. What we can do is, we make the margin on left 0 for `ul` tag. And add some left padding for `a` tags inside the nested `ul`. This will show the sub-menu indented and also make the background color occupy complete width. Need a demo? Let me know.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/D5sdT/1/ I updated the code to demo the sub menus with proper hover background. Check and let me know if it need any modifications.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your help. I implemented your last jsfiddle on this page: [goo.gl/X0VRgu](http://goo.gl/X0VRgu) but the problem is still there.

Comment: I copied the code I have implemented on jsfiddle, based on your code, and it works as it should [http://jsfiddle.net/kaY5n/](http://jsfiddle.net/kaY5n/). Any ideas why the gap on the left stays when it is implemented on wordpress?

Comment: Add `.widget-area .menuside ul li { padding : 0; margin : 0; }` and `.widget-area .menuside ul ul { margin : 0; }` to your styles. Because currently styles from `.widget-area ul li` styles are inherited to these. That's why there is a gap. Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. One last question if you don't mind. See on this page [goo.gl/aK3ipP](http://goo.gl/aK3ipP), hover your mouse over "Expertise", you will notice that the button is a little thinner than the others. It's cut at the bottom. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34768/discussion-between-vanga-sasidhar-and-douglas-edward)

Answer (score 0):

I tried playing your site and came up with this I hope this is what you want. Change your

```
.advanced-sidebar-menu li > ul li a:hover
 {
   color: black;
background-color: white;
 }
```

to

```
.advanced-sidebar-menu li > ul li:hover
 {
   color: black;
background-color: white;
 }
```